How to arrange three pictures with different sizes and large captions
So, I need to organize three images that have different sizes in the shape of two small images in a column one under the other and a third large image vertically next to the previous two.
I have found examples using tabular and minipage, and they both work with short captions. But the moment I add the captions I need, the images end up looking unorganized. How can I fix it? I've tried changing the sizes and gaps between images, but I can't manage to do it. The sizes of the images and the gaps between them are flexible, they do not need to have the specific sizes I gave them in the example (but should be approximately to them).
This is my code, which returns the three organized images if I use a short caption and then everything goes wrong if I use the needed capitons:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=5pt,singlelinecheck=off}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering    
    \begin{minipage}{0.35\columnwidth}
       \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=40mm]{example-image-a} %,height=2.5c
            \caption{Image a}
            \vspace*{9mm}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=55mm]{example-image-b} %,height=4cm
            \caption{Image B}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \enskip
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\columnwidth}
         \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=110mm]{example-image-c} %,height=83mm
            \caption{Image C}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Minipage short captions.} 
    \label{fig:SPS microstructures}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering    
    \begin{minipage}{0.35\columnwidth}
       \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=40mm]{example-image-a} %,height=2.5c
            \caption{Bimodal microstructure of ODS steel, from [1]}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=55mm]{example-image-b} %,height=4cm
            \caption{316L fine microstructure, from [2]}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \enskip
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\columnwidth}
         \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=110mm]{example-image-c} %,height=83mm
            \caption{Perlitic matrix with an ultrafine martensite-austenite constituent (shown in the dark areas from a superimposed IQ map and phase map), from [3]}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Minipage captions needed.} 
    \label{fig:SPS microstructures}
\end{figure}





\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
    \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=40mm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Bimodal microstructure of ODS steel, from [1]}
      \end{subfigure}\\
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=55mm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{316L fine microstructure, from [2]}
      \end{subfigure}
    \end{tabular}
    &
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\columnwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=110mm]{example-image-c}
      \caption{Perlitic matrix with an ultrafine martensite-austenite constituent (shown in the dark areas from a superimposed IQ map and phase map), from [3]}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{tabular}
  \label{fig:ABC}
  \caption{Tabular captions needed.}
\end{figure}


\end{document}






Welcome to TeX.SE! Where does subfigure come from? Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

to provide code we can compile to reproduce the layout, either use \rules of the relevant dimensions or use \includegraphics[width=...,height=...]{example-image-a}. that will distort the image, of course, but it will be the correct size for testing.

I made the changes suggested, I hope my problem is easier to understand now
